# Integration of the shape formula into a shader

Tags: shaders, geometry, shader-nodes

I want to create a shader with a pattern from a repeating vector shape. I have derived the math formula for this shape and now I want the vector to be output from the formula with randomly generated input values in a given numeric range every time it is iterated on a 3D object. With what node or addon can this be arranged?

Comment: All a shader knows about are attributes, (including location as measured in some coordinate space) of _the point it is currently shading_.  It can't _construct_, say, a parametric shape, in that space. Often, but by no means always, you can derive a an sdf. A function which tells the shader _how far away_  the current shading-point is, from the  shape of interest. Can you give an example?

Comment: @RobinBetts Unfortunately, I can’t share the formula of the shape now. But while studying procedural texturing, I stumbled upon the RGB Curves node in tutorials, which can determine the shape of a shape in a displacement map, which is pretty close to my needs. However, in this node, the shape of the curve is determined by the graphical editor, while I need to set the desired shape using the aforementioned mathematical formula.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  Shader nodes have math and vector math nodes with options that encompass a **lot** of operations.

Comment: @Nathan Let's say I have a function "x²+y²=c", where "c" is a value that varies randomly within [3;5]. At which node or group of nodes should I enter this formula and these input values so that my 3D object is covered with circles of different radius? Just in case, I’ll clarify that, of course, I’m not going to use mathematical formulas to obtain such primitive patterns, this is just a very simplified example.

Comment: Where you should enter it depends on what the variables x and y refer to in your equation.  Your equation doesn't make circles; it makes a circle.  You could use UV map (for a UV mapped model), separate XYZ, math/exponent, math/add, math/greater than, math/less than, math/multiply (with clamp) to make your precise expression; you could plug the output into emission color, as an example, to see it.

Comment: Although, don't test for equality; test for ranges.  3D graphics are sampled, not continuous.  Equality will be an infinitely thin line you never see.

Comment: @Nathan Yes, I sadly discovered that drawing even such a simple function in Blender requires the creation of many nodes for each primitive mathematical operation separately, and I expected to find a node or addon whose functionality would be similar to some simple function graph generator ala Graph or Desmos.com. I'll try to work with what I have, thanks for your time!